# How to count number of retweets and update database accordingly?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following tables:

```
tweets                                retweets
----------------------------------    --------------------
id  id_str             retweet_cnt    id id_str
----------------------------------    --------------------
1   46604457684901888                 1  46604457684901888
2   46556513103388672                 2  46604457684901888
3   46294368197427200                 3  46604457684901888
                                      4  46556513103388672
                                      5  46556513103388672
```

I would like to `UPDATE` `tweets.retweet_cnt` by counting for each (varchar) `id_str` how many times it occurs in `retweets`. Can anybody help me with the query for this? Important: it is possible for in `id_str` **not** to appear in `retweets` (as as the case with `46294368197427200` in the example). In that case, zero (`0`) should be returned.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `UPDATE` on tweets and join in the retweet counts per id:

```
update tweets t
left join (select id_str, count(id) as id_count
           from retweets r group by id_str) r
  on r.id_str = t.id_str
set t.retweet_cnt = coalesce(r.id_count, 0);
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e98/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id_str, COUNT(r.id)
FROM tweets t
  LEFT JOIN retweets r
  ON t.id_str = r.id_str
GROUP BY t.id_str
```